# Imported images not assigned to image, base_image and thumbnail

Tags: import, dataflow

I am working on importing products through the dataflow profiles, as the newer import is not working for unknown reasons.

I read [this article](http://www.mootpoint.org/blog/magento-bulk-product-import-images/) which recommended to import products and their images seperately from each other. That was a good idea, as all products with prices, categories etc. got imported fine and that took a lot of work from me.

I then moved on to create an `image_import.csv` which contained the sku, image, base_image and thumbnail fields.

That import also worked well and images were correctly assigned to the products based on the SKU, but they are not chosen in the backend.

It looks like this:
[image]

Am I missing something in my import file, so the images are chosen for the different image sizes?

Comment: Consider using Magmi for import, much easier and less troubles.

Comment: Mag manager is awesome

Comment: @flomei :: Did you solve your issue?